# Convex Hull Algorithm application

Tags: gesture-recognition, convex-hull

For what purpose is Convex Hull algorithm used in Hand gesture recognition using image processing in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

Gesture-recognition applications utilizes computational geometry features and algorithms. In mathematical description, **Convex Hull** is the **smallest** convex set that contains given set of points. So, you may think that; in "hand-gesture-recognition" domain the convex hull is used to find area of the hand on the given image or image stream.

Consider the example;

[image: Image 1 - Convex hull of the contour of the hand and convex defect]

The example shows the formation of the hand when all fingers are open.

Then, think about other formations of the hand;

[image: Image 2 - Other formations of hand]

Basically; you can see that for different formations results in different convex hull geometry. By inspecting geometry you can count the number of fingers open etc.

For detailed information, see [that paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6734047/).